# Regex gives different result in javascript and .NET

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I need a regex which matches pattern `name1\name2`  with the restriction that `name1` must not contain some special characters such as `<` , `>`.  `name1`, `name2` can have spaces.

I am using this regex and it seems to work fine in java script :

`/^[^ &<>;]+\\./`

In my C sharp code, I am using the regex below:

`var pattern= @"^[^ &<>;]+\\.";`

The C sharp results fail for the input : `8  [  }  \`  ;
where as it passes for javascript. 
How can I get similar results ?

Comment: Javascript: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html
C#: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

Comment: The patterns are equivalent. They work the same way in JS and .NET. That is, equally wrong. Or, you have provided incorrect requirements. Please clarify.

Comment: The `@` decorator means the C# regex contains the two characters \\ where only \ was intended.

Comment: @AlexK. A double backslash matches a single backslash in a string, it is not a problem. `@"\\"` = `/\\/`.

Comment: @AlexK. Your comment is wrong, please remove. `@"\."` matches a dot, while `@"\\."` matches a ``\`` and any char. The JS pattern matches the same: `/\\./` matches a ``\`` followed with any char.

Comment: user3054298, your regexps are equivalent. Unless you have a specific problem with them, please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with the example that you've given, you ommited space from list of allowed characters. For your example this pattern works:

```
var pattern = @"^[^&<>;]+\\.";
```

Comment: Thank you ! didn't notice the space.